# How to split the html string and get different tag with values

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

So i have a lot of html string and i want to split and get the appropriate html tags.

let the string be `<h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</h2> <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</p> <h6>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</h6> <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</h3>`

Now I want to data as

```
[
  ["h2","Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum"],
  ["p","Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum"],
  ["h6","Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum"],
  ["h3","Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum"]
[
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: He tried to get an answer on StackOverflow xD

Comment: What if there are multiple `h2` elements?

Comment: @ritaj If there are multiple h2 elements then instead of json object, we can have array of arrays. I am fine with that. Let me update the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a dummy DOM element:

```
const dummy = document.createElement("div");
```

Append your string to it as innerHTML:

```
dummy.innerHTML = 'YOUR_STRING';
```

And then you can traverse/map its children like so:

```
const mappedChildren = Array.from(dummy.children).map(child => ({ tag: child.tagName, text: child.innerHTML}));
```

Comment: No actually I am doing in React.js, so I don't want this approach.

Comment: That doesn't make a difference. I'd use this approach even in React.

Answer (score 1):

```js
const input = '<h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</h2> <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</p> <h6>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</h6> <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</h3>\n'

const parse = (s) => {
  const regex = /<(.+?)>(.+?)<\/.+?>/g;
  let match = regex.exec(s);
  const result = []
  while (match != null) {
    result.push([match[1], match[2]])
    match = regex.exec(s);
  }
  return result
}

console.log(parse(input))
```

regex will capture tags with content, capture groups will capture tagstag names and content separately from each other

Comment: I am familiar with that comment :-). However, my solution produces exact result requested by author without slow `.createElement` and without relying on browser api, which might not be available in e.g. node @ritaj

Comment: @ritaj It's correct that regex can't be used to parse HTML structures but the question was to split a list of tags and not nested tags. For that regex are the top contender. My vote goes to Max  :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can use

```js
var element = document.createElement('div');
element.innerHTML = 'your string...';
var result = [].slice.call(element.children).map(c => ([c.tagName.toLowerCase(), c.innerText]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`template`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/template).

```js
const html = "<h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</h2> <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</p> <h6>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</h6> <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</h3>";

const template = document.createElement('template');
template.innerHTML = html;
const children = template.content.children;
let result = [];
for(c of children) {
    const newEntry = [c.tagName, c.innerText];
    result = [...result, newEntry];
}
console.log(result);
```

The result is an array of arrays, like you requested.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something as simple as that?

```
var all = document.getElementsByTagName("*");

for (var i=0, max=all.length; i < max; i++) {
     console.log({all[i].tagName : all[i].innerHTML});
}
```

PS. You can change `document` to some inner element if you only need tags from a part of the site.
PPS. Ofc instead of `console.log()` you can add it to an array with `<array>.push();`

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume your lorem ipsum string is stored in the variable `lorem`. Put it into a container so you can work with it as a whole.

```
var dummyElement = document.createElement("div");
dummyElement.innerHTML = lorem;
```

*If your data is actually a part of the website, just select it's parent element that contains them.*

Now read the elements that are inside of it.

```
var elementArray = dummyElement.getElementsByTagName(""); //empty, since we want all the elements
```

You'll now have a list of HTML elements, from which you can access both their text (`elementArray[i].innerText`) as well as their tag (`elementArray[i].tagName`). You can now store it into your output array in the format you mentioned in the question by fore example cycling through them and adding them to the array.

```
var finalArray = [];
for(var i=0; i<elementArray.size; i++){
    finalArray.push([elementArray[i].tagName, elementArray[i].innerText]);
}
console.log(finalArray);
```

*There are better, more modern ways to go around this, but the above describes the principle that should be sufficient to get you started.*

Answer (score 0):

This is HTML code:

```
<div id="container">
    <h2>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</h2>
    <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</p>
    <h6>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</h6>
    <h3>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum</h3>
</div>
```

And javascript code:

```
var container = document.getElementById('container');
var result = [];
for (child of container.children) {
    var newChild = [child.tagName, child.innerText];
    result.push(newChild);
}
```